# Hebrew date picker for Access form

Tags: vba, ms-access, datepicker

Is there any functionality for the Hebrew calendar in the regular datepicker used in Access forms?

Comment: The datepicker cannot be altered. So how would you expect it to accommodate Hebrew calendar?